# Generic inheritance and type conversion

Tags: c#, generics

So I'm attempting to abstract some WPF View/View Models into decoupled reusable objects. And now I'm stuck in such a way that I'm not even sure what to try next. I am hoping someone out there can help get my brain unlocked.

Here is a simplified example and error

```
    public interface IBasicListDto{}

    public interface IBasicListVm<T> where T : IBasicListDto
    {
        void DoSomthing();
    }  

    public class BasicListVm<T> : IBasicListVm<T> where T : IBasicListDto
    {
        public void DoSomthing()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("woohoo!!");
        }
    }

   public class MyBasicListDto : IBasicListDto{}

   public class MyBasicListVm<T> : BasicListVm<T> where T : MyBasicListDto {}

   private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
        IBasicListVm<IBasicListDto> vm = (IBasicListVm<IBasicListDto>)new MyBasicListVm<MyBasicListDto>();
        vm.DoSomthing();
    }
```

I get the following run-time error on the first line in Button_Click method.

System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'MyBasicListVm`1[testGenericInheritance.MainWindow+MyBasicListDto]' to type 'IBasicListVm`1[testGenericInheritance.MainWindow+IBasicListDto]'.
  Source=testGenericInheritance
  StackTrace:

I have seen a few similar questions/answers, but my brain is just not "Getting it" enough to make needed changes.

Comment: The basic problem is the somewhat counterintuitive property where if you have the types `Parent` and its subtype `Child`, then `SomeGenericType<Child>` **is not** a subtype of `SomeGenericType<Parent>`. (The reason behind that is a fundamental one, if they were the Liskov Substitution Principle would be violated.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make `IBasicListVm<T>` covariant:

```
public interface IBasicListVm<out T> where T : IBasicListDto
{
    void DoSomthing();
}
```

Comment: That appears to invalidate the delegates and events defined in the "real" version of the interface.

Comment: @Wieknot That probably simply means your design doesn't make sense somewhere, and can't be made type-safe.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot disagree :(   back to the drawing board. But thx for the input.